# Local Development Guide from Github repo messed up?

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

don’t know what went wrong when I followed this instructions on a github repo: https://github.com/richtabor/building-blocks

> A. First, you need a WordPress Environment to run this plugin and
> start block development. The quickest way to get up and running is to
> use the provided docker setup. Install `docker-ce` and `docker-compose`
> (if necessary) by following the most recent instructions on the Docker
> site.
>
> B. Start Docker on your machine.
>
> C. In the folder of your preference, clone this project and enter the
> working directory:
>
> `git clone https://github.com/richtabor/building-blocks.git`
> `cd building-blocks`
>
> D. To start this local WordPress instance, run within
> the project: `docker-compose up -d` . Once started, WordPress should now
> be available at http://localhost:9999 . Note: When we’re done, run
> docker-compose stop to stop this local setup.

I clearly followed the steps. I did download docker desktop for mac. However, I’m not really sure about this `docker-ce` and `docker-compose` but I figured that docker desktop for mac that I download already have those things. So I ran `docker-compose up -d` and went to the localhost but I got this error message:

> Error establishing a database connection

So I looked at the docker-compost.yml in the github repo that I cloned to my local folder and here’s what it showed:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    ports:
      - 9999:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/building-blocks
      - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
```

So I concluded that maybe there’s a problem with the docker-compose.yml file?

How do I fix this?

Comment: This does not seem to be related with git or github. The `git` tag is not required.

Comment: I thought that the yml file was maybe not complete for a local environment. They could have just said in their guide to edit the .yml file to whatever we have it set up in our local docker wordpress environment. Their guide was really confusing...

Comment: looking forward to your answer soon. Thanks for your explanation too

Comment: Sorry for late reply, have posted an answer. Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

OK so you got docker mac app installed, I think this should be enough to get a local docker wp environment running.

*I find installing hidden packages globally through terminal using https://brew.sh/ is handy.*

1. Create a new empty local project folder, or ideally new remote git repo for your project then pull down the empty repo to your computer. As you are on mac, I tend to keep all local project folders in the `Sites` folder in your user directory...

[image]

[image]

2. In project folder create a file called `uploads.ini` and add this code to it...

```ini
file_uploads = On
memory_limit = 2000M
upload_max_filesize = 2000M
post_max_size = 2000M
max_execution_time = 600
```

3. Create an empty theme folder, and name the folder the same as what you intend it to be on the staging and production server environments. I'm guna use `portfolio` in this example.

[image]

4. Before dockering up a theme, it's best to add some files to you theme folder so it is a valid theme other wise it may not be you wont be able to activate it...

[image]

5. Make sure the `style.css` has valid Wordpress theme comment code...

```css
/*
Theme Name: Portfolio
Author: Kristina Bressler
Version: 1.0
License: Private
*/
```

6. Now lets create our `docker-compose.yml` configuration file in our project folder, see comments in code below...

```yml
version: '3.7'

# needed for mailhog
networks:
  wordpress:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.25.0.0/16

services:

  # here is our mysql database container
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      # our persistent local database re routing
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql:delegated

      # this is handy for dockering up from a mysql dumped existing database, not needed for new project
      #- ./docker/db-dumps:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:delegated
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      # these can be the same for every local docker project
      # never pass these to the staging or production wp-configs database settings
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wordpress

  # here is our wordpress container
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      # our persistent local data re routing
      # if you dont use persistent data then every time you docker down and docker up
      # docker will just rebuild a brand new installation and your will lose all previous session data

      # our persistent theme folder routing for portfolio theme
      # make sure this mapping matches your theme folder name (this example is portfolio)
      - ./portfolio:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/portfolio:delegated

      # our persistent plugins and uploads folder
      - ./plugins:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins
      - ./uploads:/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads

      # our persistent uploads.ini setting (uploads.ini must exist before running this)
      - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini

    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - wordpress
    environment:

      # docker wp config settings
      # these can be the same for every local docker project
      # never pass these to the staging or production wp-configs
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: wp_
      WORDPRESS_AUTH_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_SECURE_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_NONCE_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_SECURE_AUTH_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_NONCE_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb

      # extra wp configs
      WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |

        /* local parameters */
        define('WP_CACHE', false);
        define('ENVIRONMENT', 'local');
        define('WP_DEBUG', true);

        /* configure mail server */
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_AUTH', false);
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_SECURE', '');
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_HOST', 'mailhog');
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_PORT', '1025');
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_USERNAME', null);
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_PASSWORD', null);
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_FROM', 'no-reply@portfolio.com');
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_FROM_NAME', 'Portfolio');

        /* licence key defining examples - fake keys */
        define('GF_LICENSE_KEY', '567e5cc582262cea465f5ff01d3060cd');
        define('ACP_LICENCE', 'ebfb-4deb-8b1c-a580a44a-12435e03615d');

        /* if wp home is not defined */
        if(!defined('WP_HOME')) {
          /* force our home url override for permalinks and wp get functions */
          define('WP_HOME', 'http://localhost');
          define('WP_SITEURL', WP_HOME);
        }

  # here is our mail hog content
  # this creates a local mail server for see outgoing email from this wordpress site
  # access the mailbox via http://localhost:8025/
  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog:latest
    ports:
      - "8025:8025"
    networks:
      - wordpress
```

7. Before we docker up, add this code to the top of your `functions.php`. This will configure the local outgoing mail to be sent to [mailhog](https://hub.docker.com/r/mailhog/mailhog/). Plus some handy development helper functions...

```php
<?php
/**
 * @author      Kristina Bressler
 * @version     1.0
 */

// configure PHPMailer to send through smtp
add_action('phpmailer_init', function($phpmailer) {

    $phpmailer->isSMTP();
    // host details
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = WORDPRESS_SMTP_AUTH;
    $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = WORDPRESS_SMTP_SECURE;
    $phpmailer->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
    $phpmailer->Host = WORDPRESS_SMTP_HOST;
    $phpmailer->Port = WORDPRESS_SMTP_PORT;
    // from details
    $phpmailer->From = WORDPRESS_SMTP_FROM;
    $phpmailer->FromName = WORDPRESS_SMTP_FROM_NAME;
    // login details
    $phpmailer->Username = WORDPRESS_SMTP_USERNAME;
    $phpmailer->Password = WORDPRESS_SMTP_PASSWORD;

});

// stops wp error by defining valid email address from our wp config
add_filter('wp_mail_from', function() { return WORDPRESS_SMTP_FROM; } );
add_filter('wp_mail_from_name', function () { return WORDPRESS_SMTP_FROM_NAME; } );

// wp mail failed action
add_action('wp_mail_failed', function($wp_error) {

    // dump any mail errors on local and staging environments
    is('local','staging') ? dd($wp_error) : false;

}, 10, 1);

// d dump print function
function dd(...$args) {
    dump(...$args);
    exit;
}

// dump print function
function dump(...$args) {
    foreach ($args as $dump) {
        echo '<pre class="dd">' . print_r($dump, true) . '</pre>';
    }
}

// environment
function environment() {
    return defined('ENVIRONMENT') ? ENVIRONMENT : 'production';
}

// is environment
function is(...$environments) {
    foreach ($environments as $environment) {
        if($environment === environment())
            return true;
    }
}
```

8. Now we are ready to docker up, your folder structure should looks like this...

[image]

9. To build this environment using docker, you need to run this command `docker-compose up -d` on the `project` folder containing the `.yml` file.

> You may run into some problems if you have not run `docker-compose down` on the building blocks plugin `.yml` parent folder you've already run. You will need to stop any running docker environments for the above to work. This is the same with all your docker projects going forward, you can't docker `docker-compose up -d` on project if another one is already running. Simply run `docker-compose down` on the running environment to shut it down.

10. If you have successfully run `docker-compose up -d` on our `project` folder, you will notice your project folder structure now looks like this...

[image]

11. Now simply visit http://localhost to complete the Wordpress installation process...

[image]

12. Once installed you will need to activate our portfolio theme...

[image]

13. Once theme is activated you can see outgoing email from this local Wordpress environment via mailhog by simply visiting http://localhost:8025...

[image]

14. If you are using git you should add a `.gitignore` file to your project folder. You do not want to be committing folders `db`, `plugins` and `uploads` to your repo. These are very large in file size and not project code. Find other means to back these up like google drive backup sync or something...

```gitignore
/db
/plugins
/uploads
/portfolio/dist
/portfolio/node_modules
/portfolio/vendor
```

15. To get the https://github.com/richtabor/building-blocks plugin installed, simply download or clone this repo to the `plugins` folder in your local project...

[image]

16. Then go to plugins section in the Wordpress dashboard, and activate the Building Blocks plugin...

[image]

And you are done!

To stop and remove the environment simply run `docker-compose down` on the project folder.

Now you can safely `docker-compose up -d` on another project.

A few notes...

- Our persistent mapping in our `docker-compose.yml` allows us to docker up a project with all the same file data and mysql data we had when we last dockered down the environment. Without these persistent mappings, docker will rebuild an entire new installation from the [Wordpress docker hub image](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress).
- Don't sync `db`, `plugins` and `uploads` data from local to staging/production environments. Manually manage `plugins` on environments. `uploads` and database are independent to each environment.
- You can carefully dump specific local database tables as inserts and import/replace them into staging/production databases if you need too. I just dont recommend doing this with entire local database dumps.
- Dumping entire staging/production databases, and loading them into local docker environment is absolutely fine, just not the other way round.
- `wp-config.php` on staging/production environments ideally need to manually managed and not synced from local environments. Not included in repos just incase.

Comment: Looks good! I'll have to try it out. But why do I need mailhog? It looks like you use it for email which I don't need when I'm editing the plugin?

Comment: Sorry I missed understood the question. I thought you wanted to install the plugin to use on a local project, not to edit the plugin. The answer above is a bit overkill then. You can just update the plugin yml to this... https://gist.github.com/joshmoto/ec7223c40bf7f6378094cd06b6006221

Comment: I cant seem to get npm to install correctly though.