# How do I access the Docker CE virtual machine on MacOS BigSur?

Tags: docker

I'm running the Docker community edition on MacOS BigSur (11.2.2), and am trying to get into the virtual environment.

[This article](https://collabnix.com/how-docker-for-mac-works-under-the-hood/) from 2018 says to do

`$screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty`

and [this one](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/where-are-docker-images-stored-docker-container-paths-explained/) from February 2020 says

`$ screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty`

But neither of those things seem to work in my current install.

`$docker --version Docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The methods you have found are `backdoors` for entering in the virtual machine, and they change when the releases are changing, and both mentioned methods are no longer supported on the latest Docker-for-mac.

The most canonical way to get terminal access to the virtual machine (create a `sh` process in the virtual machine and get `tty` from it), you need the following command.

```
docker run -it --privileged --pid=host debian nsenter -t 1 -m -u -n -i sh
```

This approach will create a container and will join it to the namespace of the host, after which it will create a new shell in the namespace of the `init` (`pid 1`) by executing the `nsenter` command. This will not change much with the later releases since it relies on stabile docker features to get the access to the vm. In the example I had used `debian`, but you can replace this with any image that has `nsenter` (ex. `alpine`, `busybox`, etc.)

Also, you can get access trough the current debug socket which will create a shell directly in the virtual machine and connect to it. This is more a `backdor` created for debugging and might be removed/changed in future releases.

```
stty -echo -icanon && nc -U ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/debug-shell.sock && stty sane
```

Comment: The second answer got me in. The first ("most canonical") wanted to have debian (`Unable to find image 'debian:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/debian`). Once I got in using the second method, `uname -a` says `Linux docker-desktop 4.19.121-linuxkit #1 SMP Thu Jan 21 15:36:34 UTC 2021 x86_64 Linux`. Should I use a different arg than debian in the first method?

Comment: You can use `docker pull debian` to get the image. In fact, you can use any image that has the `nsenter`. It works with `alpine:latest` as well . I had updated the answer to clarify this part.

Comment: For those curious about that `nsenter` command, expanded out it is `nsenter --target 1 --mount --uts --net --ipc`, i.e., enter the disk and network and ipc namespaces for pid 1. UTS ‘UNIX Time-Sharing’ refers to the [hostname and domain name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_namespaces#UTS). `--target=1 --all` seems to work as well for me.

Answer (score 0):

If the answer by jordanvrtanoski does not work for you, try this instead:

```
docker run -it --rm --privileged --pid=host justincormack/nsenter1
```

Apparently there is a [bug](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/359) with the standard nsenter and the fix / workaround is here: [justincormack/nsenter1](https://github.com/justincormack/nsenter1)